# Additivity of Lebesgue integral w.r.t. sets on non-finite domain

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I [know](http://librarum.org/book/10022/154) that for any Lebesgue integrable function $f:X\to\mathbb{C}$, or $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$, where $X$ is a set of finite measure such that $X=\bigcup_n A_n$, $\forall i\ne j\quad A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset$, the following equality holds$$\int_X fd\mu=\sum_n\int_{A_n}fd\mu$$where the existence of the first integral implies the existence of the integrals in the second member of the equality.

Then I read that it also holds if $X$ is not of finite measure, but can be represented as the union of countably many sets of finite measure such that $X=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty X_k$ and $X_1\subset X_2\subset...$. In that case, the integral is defined by $\int_X fd\mu:=\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{X_k} fd\mu$.

I wonder how the equality above can be generalised in such a case. I guess that a way to prove it might be taking limits in the equality above, which is valid for any $X_k$: $\int_{X_k} fd\mu=\sum_n\int_{A_n\cap X_k}fd\mu$. I would understand why it holds if I could see that $\int_X fd\mu:=\lim_{k}\int_{X_k}fd\mu=\lim_k\sum_n\int_{A_n\cap X_k}fd\mu$ is equal to $\sum_n\lim_k\int_{A_n\cap X_k}fd\mu=\sum_n\int_{A_n}fd\mu$, but I do not know whether and why it would be possible to "move the limit(s) across the $\sum$". I heartily thank you for any help!

EDIT: I have realised that it may well be necessary that for any $n$ and $k$ $A_n\cap X_k$ be measurable. The text does not specify the condition, but I think it's quite obvious.

Comment: Dominated convergence?

Comment: Thank you so much!!! My book proves the dominated convergence theorem for domains of finite measure and I've been able to prove it for domains $X$ of the form described before, but I don't see how we could use it here... P.S.: I think the theorem you refer to is this theorem 1 that I know in this form: http://librarum.org/book/10022/156

Comment: Look at $f$ and at $f\chi_{S_{n}}$, where $\chi_{S}$ is the characteristic function of a set. Use $|f\chi_{S_{n}}|\le |f|$.

Comment: Thank you again!!! Forgive me: never used characteristic functions (not described in my book, Kolmogorov-Fomin's) until now. If the $S_n$ are measurable, then I'd say $f_{\chi_{S_n}}$ is measurable and, if $\forall x\in X\quad\lim_n f_{\chi_{S_n}}(x)=\phi(x)$, $\lim_n \int_X f_{\chi_{S_n}}d\mu=\int_X\phi d\mu$, but I don't see how to use it here...

Comment: That's $f$ times $\chi_{S_{n}}$. (Yours looks like a subscript.) If $S_{n}=\cup_{j=1}^{n}A_{n}$, then $\lim_{n} f\chi_{S_{n}}$ converges pointwise everywhere to $f\chi_{S}$ where $S=\cup_{j=1}^{\infty}A_{n}$, and $f_{n}=f\chi_{S_{n}}$ remains uniformly bounded by $|f|$ during that convergence. So, if $f$ is integrable, then $\int_{S_{n}}f\,d\mu=\int f\chi_{S_{n}}d\mu$ converges to $\int_{S}f\,d\mu=\int f\chi_{S}\,d\mu$.

Comment: Forgive me: I believed it to be a subscript: no practice with characteristic functions and their notation. I heartily thank you!  With $S_k=A_n\cap X_k$, I see that $\lim_k\int_{A_n\cap X_k}fd\mu=\lim_k\int_X f\chi_{A_n\cap X_k}d\mu=\int_X f\chi_{A_n}d\mu=\int_{A_n}fd\mu$, therefore I see that the integrals of the $2^\text{nd}$ member exist...

Comment: ...but I still cannot realise why $\int_X fd\mu$ (i.e. $\lim_k\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{A_n\cap X_k}fd\mu$ which is the same as $\lim_k\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_X f\chi_{A_n\cap X_k}d\mu$) is the same thing as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{A_n}fd\mu$, which I understand to be $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\lim_k\int_{A_n\cap X_k}fd\mu=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\lim_k\int_X f\chi_{A_n\cap X_k}d\mu$... P.S.: edited the OP